# How to zip a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
sample = [['A','T','N','N'],['T', 'C', 'C', 'C']],[['A','T','T','N'],['T', 'T', 'C', 'C']].
```

I am trying to zip the file such that only A/T/G/C are in lists and the output needs to be a list

```
[['AT','TCCC'],['ATT','TTCC']]
```

When I use this code:

```
tt = ["".join(y for y in x if y in {'A','G','T','C'}) for x in sample]
```

However, I only get the output as:

```
['ATT','TTCC']
```

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

In my actual code I am first transposing the lists:

```
seq_list = [['TCCGGGGGTATC', 'TCCGTGGGTATC', ...]]  # one nested list

numofpops = len(seq_list)

### Tranposing. Moving along the columns only

#column_list = []
for k in range(len(seq_list)):
    column_list = [[] for i in range(len(seq_list[k][0]))]
    for seq in seq_list[k]:
        for i, nuc in enumerate(seq):
            column_list[i].append(nuc)
            ddd = column_list
    print ddd

tt = ["".join(y for y in x if y in {'A','G','T','C'}) for x in ddd]
print tt
```

Comment: I suspect that the tag [zip] you used is not what you mean. Your `sample` also doesn't look like a list of lists.

Comment: You are not zipping (pairing up elements from separate sequences), you are joining and filtering here.

Comment: Your `sample` is not a valid Python expression. Could you please make it one? We can hardly help when input data is invalid. Your sample code and actual output show that only the second half of the `sample` expression is actually used as input.

Comment: I have printed out the code exactly the way it appears. Here is the link to me entire code with input and output https://eval.in/658325

Comment: Your `sample` is missing a comma, preventing it from being a valid list literal

Comment: @Biotechgeek: you are printing `ddd` but not adding it to a list. You then only handle the *last* result that was assigned to `ddd`. So you only have *one* such result, not multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual code is *discarding lists*. You only ever process the *last entry*.

Your code works fine otherwise. Just do that *in the loop* and then append the result to some final list:

```
results = []

for k in range(len(seq_list)):
    column_list = [[] for i in range(len(seq_list[k][0]))]
    for seq in seq_list[k]:
        for i, nuc in enumerate(seq):
            column_list[i].append(nuc)
    # process `column_list` here, in the loop (no need to assign to ddd)
    tt = ["".join(y for y in x if y in {'A','G','T','C'}) for x in column_list]

    results.append(tt)
```

Note that you could use the `zip()` function instead of your transposition list:

```
results = []
for sequence in seq_list:
    for column_list in zip(*sequence):
        tt = [''.join([y for y in x if y in 'AGTC']) for x in column_list]
        results.append(tt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the following:

```
sample = [[['A','T','N','N'],['T', 'C', 'C', 'C']], [['A','T','T','N'],['T', 'T', 'C', 'C']]]
```

And then:

```
tt = [[''.join([c for c in sublist if c in 'AGTC']) for sublist in doublet] for doublet in sample]
```

Perhaps more readable this way:

```
tt = [
    [''.join([c for c in sublist if c in 'AGTC'])
     for sublist in doublet]
    for doublet in sample
]
```

It gives the desired result:

```
[['AT', 'TCCC'], ['ATT', 'TTCC']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a helper function:

```
def filterJoin(s):
    return ''.join(x for x in s if x in 'ATGC')
```

Then:

```
>>> sample = [['A','T','N','N'],['T', 'C', 'C', 'C']],[['A','T','T','N'],['T', 'T', 'C', 'C']]
>>> [[filterJoin(s) for s in t] for t in sample]
[['AT', 'TCCC'], ['ATT', 'TTCC']]
```

Comment: And the real problem is that the OP misunderstood `print` for appending to a list.. They have a loop where the list is set and only after the loop is done do they use the last list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I posted the answer before OP edited the code in. I'll keep it since the idea of using a helper function is fairly natural here, although your justly accepted answer (+1) shows what the actual problem was.

Comment: Which is why I tried to get the OP to fix their sample; they were doing the right thing for one such list, and it was the last one. And then they posted their actual code in a comment (which I then added to the question) showing that this was all an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input you've given are two items in one list. Then, you would use a *list comprehension* with 2 levels of nesting. At the deepest level, you filter out items that are not `A, T, G` or `C` and then `join` the others:

```
sample =  [[['A','T','N','N'],['T', 'C', 'C', 'C']], [['A','T','T','N'],['T', 'T', 'C', 'C']]]

result = [[''.join(i for i in lst if i in 'ATGC') for lst in sub] for sub in sample]
#                                  ^<- filter items
#           ^<- join the matching items
print(result)
# [['AT', 'TCCC'], ['ATT', 'TTCC']]
```