# How to use counters and zip functions with a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, error-handling, append

I have a list of lists :

```
results = [['TTTT', 'CCCZ'], ['ATTA', 'CZZC']]
```

I create a counter that stores number number of characters in each element in each list, only if the characters are ATGC [NOT Z]

```
The desired output is [[4,3],[4,2]]
```

**

Code:

```
counters = [Counter(sub_list) for sub_list in results]
    nn =[]
    d = []
    for counter in counters:
            atgc_count = sum((val for key, val in counter.items() if key in "ATGC"))    
            nn.append(atgc_count)
d = [i - 1 for i in nn]
correctionfactor = [float(b) / float(m) for b,m in zip(nn, d)]
print nn
print correctionfactor

"Failed" Output:
[0, 0]
<closed file 'c:/test/zzz.txt', mode 'r' at 0x02B46078>

Desired Output
nn = [[4,3],[4,2]]
correctionfactor = [[1.33, 1.5],[1.33,2]]
```

**

And then I calculate frequency of each character (pi), square it and then sum (and then I calculate het = 1 - sum).

```
The desired output [[1,2],[1,2]] #NOTE: This is NOT the real values of expected output. I just need the real values to be in this format.
```

**
Code

```
list_of_hets = []
for idx, element in enumerate(sample):
    count_dict = {}
    square_dict = {}
    for base in list(element):
         if base in count_dict:
            count_dict[base] += 1
        else:
            count_dict[base] = 1
    for allele in count_dict:
        square_freq = (count_dict[allele] / float(nn[idx]))**2
        square_dict[allele] = square_freq        
    pf = 0.0
    for i in square_dict:
        pf += square_dict[i]   # pf --> pi^2 + pj^2...pn^2
    het = 1-pf                    
    list_of_hets.append(het)
print list_of_hets

"Failed" OUTPUT:
[-0.0, -0.0]
```

**
I need to multiply every elements in list_of_hets by correction factor

```
h = [float(n) * float(p) for n,p in zip(correction factor,list_of_hets)
With the values given above:
h = [[1.33, 1.5],[1.33,2]] #correctionfactor multiplied by list_of_hets
```

Finally, I need to find the average value of every element in h and store it in a new list.

```
The desired output should read as [1.33, 1.75].
```

I tried following this example ([Sum of list of lists; returns sum list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783315/sum-of-list-of-lists-returns-sum-list)).

```
hs = [mean(i) for i in zip(*h)]
```

But I get the following error "TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration"

I understand that correcting the code at the first step may solve it. I tried to manually input the "desired outputs" and run the rest of the code, but no luck.

Comment: What is `l` in `zip(*l)` ???

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966187/how-to-zip-a-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Shouldn't the desired output in your first example for `results = [['TTTT', 'CCCZ'], ['ATTA', 'CZZC']]` be `[[4,3],[4,2]]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : I have corrected your concerns. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @mhawke: I have corrected your concerns. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @leaf: Its an extension of the question, related though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part can be done like this:

```
BASES = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'}

results = [['TTTT', 'CCCZ'], ['ATTA', 'CZZC']]
counts = [[sum(c in BASES for c in s) for s in pair] for pair in results]
>>> counts
[[4, 3], [4, 2]]
```

Once you have the counts, the correction factor can also be calculated with a list comprehension:

```
correction_factors = [[i/float(i-1) for i in pair] for pair in counts]
>>> correction_factors
[[1.3333333333333333, 1.5], [1.3333333333333333, 2.0]]
```

but you do need to be careful of the case where a count is 1 as this will lead to a division by zero error. I'm not sure how you should handle that... would a value of `1` be appropriate?

```
correction_factors = [[i/float(i-1) if i-1 else 1 for i in pair] for pair in counts]
```

Comment: I need to put in a correction factor which is counts/(counts-1).  Correctionfactor = banansplit (I have made the change). tt = sample (I have made the change)

Comment: I modified your command for Part1 as `d = [[(sum(c in BASES for c in s)-1) for s in pair] for pair in results]`
`correctionfactor = [float(b) / float(m) for b,m in zip(counts, d)]` . However, correctionfactor seems to be giving an error

Comment: @Biotechgeek: re the correction factor, what will you do if there is only one valid base? e.g. correction factor for `ZZZA` will lead to a division by zero error.

Comment: I know, that's a limitation to this approach. We handle that in a separate way and so I did not incorporate it into this as it may confuse the audience.

Answer (score 0):

First map traverse results.
Second map replace 'Z' and count element.

```
map(lambda x:map(lambda y:len(y.replace('Z','')),x),l)
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to get correctionfactor or list_of_hets working?

Comment: Correctionfactor is just nn divided by d. (i.e.nn divided by (nn-1)). However, I cannot do a straightforward division. I get this error:TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number